# Python txt file tag parse

Tags: python, parsing, text

I am trying to parse out the contents of two different tags in a txt file and I am getting all the instances of the first tag "p" but not the second "l". Is the problem with the "or"?

Thanks for the help. Here is the code I am using

```
with open('standardA00456.txt','w') as output_file:
    with open('standardA00456.txt','r') as open_file:
            the_whole_file = open_file.read()
            start_position = 0

            while True:

               start_position = the_whole_file.find('<p>' or '<l>', start_position)

               end_position = the_whole_file.find('</p>' or '</l>', start_position)
               data = the_whole_file[start_position:end_position+5]


               output_file.write(data + "\n")
               start_position = end_position
```

Comment: `'<p>' or '<l>'` will always equal `'<p>'`.

Comment: This is an HTML or XML file, not a plain text file, right? Because text files don't have "tags", they have no more structure beyond characters and lines. And I'm not bringing this up to be pedantic; if you want to parse HTML or XML, you should be using a parser, like `ElementTree` or `BeautifulSoup`, not trying to do it this way.

Comment: I appreciate your comment and If I was trying to parse an xml file it would be the proper way. The file I have is a txt file that has been manually marked with html-like tags. I don't know how to use element tree so an example would be helpful.

Comment: @EnglishGrad: Then google for "ElementTree example" or "ElementTree tutorial" or similar. Any example someone gives you in a comment here will be nowhere near as good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'<p>' or '<l>'` will always equal `'<p>'`, as it tells Python to use `'<l>'` only if `'<p>'` is `None`, `False`, numeric zero, or empty. And as the string `'<p>'` is never one of those, `'<l>'` is always skipped:

```
>>> '<p>' or '<l>'
'<p>'
>>> None or '<l>'
'<l>'
```

Instead you can easily use `re.findall`:

```
import re
with open('standardA00456.txt','w') as out_f,  open('standardA00456.txt','r') as open_f:
    p_or_ls = re.findall(r'(?:<p>.*?</p>)|(?:<l>.*?</l>)', 
                         open_f.read(), 
                         flags=re.DOTALL) #to include newline characters
    for p_or_l in p_or_ls:
        out_f.write(p_or_l + "\n")
```

However, parsing files with tags (such as HTML and XML) using regex is **[not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454)**. Using a module, such as [BeautifulSoup](https://wiki.python.org/moin/beautiful%20soup) is safer:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('standardA00456.txt','w') as out_f,  open('standardA00456.txt','r') as open_f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open_f.read())
    for p_or_l in soup.find_all(["p", "l"]):
        out_f.write(p_or_l + "\n")
```

Comment: Minor quibble: Falsey is usually described as "`None`, `False`, **numeric zero**, or empty". Sure, `0` is literally empty if you're defining numbers on top of set theory, but I don't think most people think of numbers that way.

Comment: @abarnert You're right, thank you. I edited my answer to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

English Grad, I think you need to improve the logic. I modified your code and came up with this:

```
with open('standardA00456.txt','w') as output_file:
    with open('standardA00456.txt','r') as open_file:
        the_whole_file = open_file.read()
        start_position = 0

        found_p = False
        fould_l = False

        while True:
            start_pos_p = the_whole_file.find('<p>', start_position)
            start_pos_l = the_whole_file.find('<l>', start_position)

            if start_pos_p > -1 and start_pos_l > -1:
                if start_pos_p < start_pos_l:
                    found_p = True
                    start_position = start_pos_p
                    found_l = False
                else:
                    found_l = True
                    start_position = start_pos_l
                    found_p = False
            elif start_pos_p > -1:        
                found_p = True
                start_position = start_pos_p
                found_l = False
            elif start_pos_l > -1:        
                found_l = True
                start_position = start_pos_l
                found_p = False
            else:
                break

            if found_p:
                end_position = the_whole_file.find('</p>', start_position)

            elif found_l:
                end_position = the_whole_file.find('</l>', start_position)

            else:
                break

            data = the_whole_file[start_position:end_position+5]
            output_file.write(data + "\n")
            start_position = end_position
```

Comment: This is a bit excessive, when the same can be done with 5 lines of code.

Comment: What if someone doesn't want to use regular expression or parsing library like beautiful soup? I just improved his code a bit and this should solve his problem.